# why `typeof Map2<any>` returns a hint of 'number'?

Tags: typescript

The code is simple. Is that a bug for TS or VScode?

```
interface Map2<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}
type XXX = keyof Map2<string>
     //hint~ type XXX = string | number
```

```
interface Map2<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}
type XXX = keyof Map2<boolean>
     //hint~ type XXX = string | number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. This behavior was [introduced in TypeScript 2.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types).  From the documentation:

> Given an object type `X`, `keyof X` is resolved as follows:
>
> - If `X` contains a string index signature, `keyof X` is a union of `string`, `number`, and the literal types representing symbol-like properties

The reason why this was done is to deal with the fact that TypeScript has the concept of `number` keys, even though JavaScript really doesn't.  But TypeScript *pretends* that `number` is a valid key type for an object.

All non-symbol keys in JavaScript are actually [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), even the indexing keys of arrays. (e.g., `Object.keys(["a","b"])` returns `["0", "1"]`)  When you index into an array with a number, as in `arr[0]`, the index is [coerced into a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Property_names) first and is treated like `arr["0"]`.  Therefore an object with a `string` index can still be treated as an array-like object with numeric keys, as they will be coerced to `string` when you use them.

In a fully sound and ideal TypeScript type system, there'd be a type called [`NumericString`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6346#issuecomment-169086219) which is the subtype of `string` corresponding to the output of `String(n)` for all `number` values of `n`.  And TypeScript would automatically coerce `number` to `NumericString` when you index into an object with it.  In that hypothetical world, a `string` index would just be a `string` index, and you'd still be able to use it like an array, and there'd be no incentive for anyone to want to add `number` to `keyof {[k: string]: any}`.

In this world, though, where arrays are represented in TypeScript as having `number` keys, there's an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13715) if you only treat `string` keys as non-`number` keys.  You'd get `keyof {[n: number]: any}` is `never`.  Instead of fixing it by removing `number` indices and changing them to `NumericString`, they addressed it by adding `number` as a pseudo-subtype of `string` that only appears when you look at object keys.

So, there you go.  It's intentional.  If you don't want to see `number` in your `string`, you can use the suggested [workaround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#recommendations) of replacing `keyof X` with `Extract<keyof X, string>`.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!